# How do I efficiently replace elements in the first column of a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D matrix: size(data) = [100, 3, 500]
I want to replace all the -1s in the first column with 1s.
Then, I want to replace all the -1s in the second and third columns with 0s.

Linear indexing doesn't seem to work because I have to replace the second and third column as well.

Comment: When you say "all three columns", does that mean "everything"? Because (in matlab terminology) your matrix has 100 rows, 3 columns and 500 pages. If this is true, a simple data(data == -1) = 0; will suffice.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I edited it.
I want to replace the -1 in the first column by 1 and the -1s in the remaining columns by 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
col1 = data(:,1,:);
col1(col1 == -1) = 1;
data(:,1,:) = col1;
```

etc...?